# Windows File Server Migration - Without Trust

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, file-permissions

We are about to migrate our file server (Windows Server 2012) from its current domain to a new domain.

Due to issues outside my control, there will be no domain trusts or even DNS forwarders from the new domain back to the old domain. So, I need a way to replace the ACLs with the groups and user names from the new domain. Group names will be the same, but username structure has changed, so there will be a mapping file involved.

I found [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/feature-set/) while I was searching, but I can't tell from my initial reading if it needs to have access to both domains. If it needs that, then I'm out of luck. I'm really hoping to avoid manually rebuilding permissions on our entire file server, so hopefully somebody has a good solution.

Comment: So practically you need a way to mass-apply new permissions ?

Comment: https://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/07/howto-reacling-a-file-server-in-a-domain-migration-with-setacl-3-0/

Comment: @Overmind yes, we need to mass-apply new permissions.

Comment: @joeqwerty that is one I found. I can't tell though from reading if that tool needs access to the old domain and the new domain. I'm worried that once we take the server out of the old domain, it won't be able to match everything up since the mapping file would be usernames not SID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up trying everything I could think of and never got SetACL to work. By using a mapping file with the old SIDs mapped to the accounts in the new domain I was able to get it to run through with no errors. It actually said it was applying the ACLs. But it never actually changed any permissions. Had the same results when doing it manually one at a time. I'm assuming this is because it can't reach out to the old domain, so it just skips along to the next one. In the end, I went back to the old domain and used a PS script to export the current permissions. Then did a quick edit to that CSV to change the accounts listed to the new ones, then went back to the new domain and ran a different PS script to import and apply the permissions.

Scrips I used came from [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28654041/How-to-Migrate-File-Folder-permissions-between-different-domains.html). And since I was moving the data instead of copying it over, I didn't have the issue in the linked solution regarding inherited permissions. Came out flawless.

Here is the script that was asked for. One change I made, I was redoing the folder structure (say moving from N:\share over to Z:\public) so in between the two scripts I just edited the CSV to reference the new location.

```
ExportPermissions.ps1

$sourceFolder = "E:\sourceFolder"
$exportFile = "C:\outputCSV.csv"

Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder -Recurse | ?{ $_.PsIsContainer } | %{
  $Path = $_.FullName
  # Exclude inherited rights from the report
  (Get-Acl $Path).Access | ?{ !$_.IsInherited } | Select-Object `
    @{n='Path';e={ $Path }}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType, `
    InheritanceFlags, PropagationFlags, FileSystemRights
} | Export-CSV $exportFile
```

---

```
importpermissions.ps1

$par = Import-Csv -Path "c:\outputCSV.csv"

foreach ( $i in $par ) { 
  $path= $i.Path
  $IdentityReference= $i.IdentityReference
  $AccessControlType=$i.AccessControlType
  $InheritanceFlags= $i.InheritanceFlags
  $PropagationFlags=$i.PropagationFlags
  $FileSystemRights=$i.FileSystemRights
  echo $path $IdentityReference
  $acl = Get-Acl $path
  $permission = $IdentityReference, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, 
  $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType
  $accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
  $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
  #$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($IdentityReference, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
  #$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE)
  $acl | Set-Acl $path
}
```

Comment: would you be kind enough to share the script? The link you provided requires a membership to view.

Comment: @Nelson its a bit long to post as a reply here, so I'll add another answer down below where I can actually include the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **icacls** to export and import your permissions, while also replacing any group/user.

Example: `icacls D:\Main /save Main_Perms.cfg /t /c`

If needed, the saved file can be altered and adapted to new user names. Replacing a specific user name group is just a mass-rename in the file of the NTFS S-ID.

Then you can import them back: `icacls D:\ /restore Main_Perms.cfg /t /c`

Note: when restoring permissions from the file, you should specify the path to the parent directory instead.